# Split long gtsummary() table to n smaller tables

Tags: r, split, gtsummary

While creating my descriptive table with the gtsummary() package I get a very long table.
Is it possible to split such a table in multiple shorter tables?

With this example dataset I would like to show what I mean:

```
library(gtsummary)
# make dataset with a few variables to summarize
trial2 <- trial %>% select(age, grade, response, trt)

# summarize the data with our package
table1 <- tbl_summary(trial2)
table1
```

**gives this output:**

[image]

**desired output:**

[image]

**I tried:**

```
library(gtsummary)
# make dataset with a few variables to summarize
trial2 <- trial %>% select(age)
trial3 <- trial %>% select(grade)
trial4 <- trial %>% select(response)
trial5 <- trial %>% select(trt)

# summarize the data with our package
table1 <- tbl_summary(trial2)
table2 <- tbl_summary(trial3)
table3 <- tbl_summary(trial4)
table4 <- tbl_summary(trial5)

table1
table2
table3
table4
```

Comment: do you want to keep it as one table and then have that table wrap at a certain length?

Comment: The issue is that my original table lasts over 3 pages. My idea was to split the table in 2 pieces and show them side by side. I was wondering if this is possible per code.

Comment: I would also check whether the output types, i.e. gt, flextable, huxtable, etc., Have any built-in ways to split the tables across pages. Although, these solutions wouldn't respect the variable groupings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: This code has been functionalized and put in a package. Here is the help file https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/tbl_split.html

Interesting, I've never thought about splitting a gtsummary table.  It is straight-forward enough to do, and I've written a small function to do it saved in this GitHub Gist
https://gist.github.com/ddsjoberg/1f400732f0bf9bc9ae6ad1dd8b1cf914

The function takes a gtsummary tbl as the input, as well as the variable names where you would like the split to occur. It then returns a list of gtsummary tables, each a subset of the input tbl.

```r
tt <- 
  trial %>%
  tbl_summary(by = trt) %>%
  add_p()

split_gtsummary_tbl(tt, .split_after = c("marker", "grade"))
```

If this is something that you think would be helpful to many users, please make a feature request at https://github.com/ddsjoberg/gtsummary/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=feature_request.md&title= . We can then incorporate a robust function to split the tbls.

Comment: This is perfect Daniel D. Sjoberg. Indeed, in certain situations, especially at the beginning of data analysis summary tables with all variables are an important feature. I like the design and the functionality of gtsummary tables so I asked for this feature. One more question: This may be off topic, but would you provide a saving option within your code of the tables (like table1.png, table2.png etc...). Thank you for your great job.

Comment: Here's an example how to can save a gtsummary to a png. http://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/articles/rmarkdown.html#images-1 This method works for saving to RTF, HTML, etc as well.

Comment: With my dataframe I get this error: `Fehler: Can't coerce element 1 from a double to a integer`. Can you help? I can traceback or debug. But I think the comment area is not appropriate for this.

Comment: Create a reprex and I can take a look

Comment: Thank you for your reply: I have started a new question here: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66135460/error-cant-coerce-element-1-from-a-double-to-a-integer-when-try-to-split-gtsuml>

Comment: Hi @DanielD.Sjoberg, thanks for the fix, but the function didn't seem to make it into your bstfun packaage that you linked, unless the name changed, as far as I can tell. Is it available anywhere else?

Comment: Updated the link. The function has been migrated to gtsummary