# Error: Can't coerce element 1 from a double to a integer when try to split gtsummary table

Tags: r, error-handling, split, gtsummary

This question has raised after clearing this question: [Split long gtsummary() table to n smaller tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66119997/split-long-gtsummary-table-to-n-smaller-tables)
In essence the solved question worked properly with the example database. After applying it to my own dataframe the `Error: Can't coerce element 1 from a double to a integer when try to split gtsummary table`occured.
I tried a few things like cleaning the class, removing the atrributes etc... But had no success:
here is my code:

```
library(gt)
library(gtsummary)
library(tidyverse)
# split function by Daniel D. Sjoberg

split_gtsummary_tbl <- function(x, .split_after) {
  # get row index where splits occur
  df_index <-
    .split_after %>% 
    purrr::map_int(~x$table_body$variable %in% .x %>%
                     which() %>%
                     max()) %>%
    {union(., nrow(x$table_body))} %>%
    sort() %>%
    unique() %>%
    {tibble::tibble(..index.. = .)} %>%
    mutate(..group.. = dplyr::row_number())
  
  # nest `x$table_body` within each group
  nested_table_body <-
    x$table_body %>%
    dplyr::mutate(..index.. = dplyr::row_number()) %>%
    dplyr::left_join(df_index, by = "..index..") %>%
    tidyr::fill(..group.., .direction = "up") %>%
    tidyr::nest(data = -..group..)
  
  # return gtsummary tbl list
  purrr::map(
    seq_len(nrow(nested_table_body)),
    function(..group..) {
      x$table_body <- nested_table_body$data[[..group..]]
      x
    }
  )
}

# my dataframe and applied split function

df <- structure(list(A = c(17729L, 17131L, 20617L, 18028L, 19721L, 
20418L, 17828L, 21115L, 17928L, 19721L, 17131L, 19522L, 17131L, 
19920L, 19123L, 16036L, 18028L, 17231L, 22012L, 14840L, 24502L, 
19024L, 17729L, 19721L, 20318L, 21215L, 20020L, 18625L, 18824L, 
17131L, 19920L, 16733L, 15737L, 19522L, 18426L, 16832L), B = c(14037L, 
12886L, 11150L, 13571L, 15435L, 14298L, 15188L, 17953L, 15198L, 
13135L, 14899L, 12061L, 11087L, 12825L, 14142L, 15426L, 14960L, 
13814L, 4434L, 6678L, 23550L, 9417L, 13988L, 13734L, 14087L, 
17524L, 16874L, 13605L, 15501L, 13814L, 12164L, 8219L, 12588L, 
14633L, 15746L, 10999L), C = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), D = c(43L, 34L, 
43L, 52L, 62L, 50L, 49L, 65L, 46L, 63L, 47L, 58L, 61L, 51L, 62L, 
55L, 57L, 71L, 50L, 34L, 42L, 58L, 43L, 64L, 40L, 58L, 49L, 64L, 
67L, 63L, 48L, 22L, 74L, 64L, 53L, 56L)), row.names = c(NA, -36L
), class = "data.frame")

table1 <- tbl_summary(df) 
table1 

split_gtsummary_tbl(table1, .split_after = c("marker", "B"))
```

Comment: I am not at a computer to check this....but it looks like you're trying to split the table after the marker variable and there is no variable called marker in your example dataset?

Comment: Oh that's embrassing. Thank you DD Sjoberg. `split_gtsummary_tbl(table1, .split_after = "B")`. Solves the problem.

Comment: No worries....a proper version of this function would have checks written into it to check for these things.  When we're left to base R error messaging, everything is mysterious!